How to create many lights in Godot?

I tried to add some lights to my game but I found that if I added more than 16 lights, some of them would not behave as expected.
I googled it and found that it is a limitation of the engine. I also tried the Add blend mode of Sprite2D but it didn't work well in very dark nights. So, if I want to add many lights to the scene, is it possible?

"I googled ..... is a limitation of the engine" Please add the info your found. Now we have to use Google to, to see if one have smarter search words than you. And stackoverflow is not a Google-game....

In general, you should try to optimize GPU-intensive stuff, like lights. For example, every one of those hanging lanterns can be “lit” using a texture (or a shader), which requires far fewer resources to compute, and leaving you with extra resources to throw at more important things happening in the scene.

There are a few ways you could tackle this issue, here is a brief list of solutions:
(Apologies if any of these are not possible or reasonable)

Have one light source for a group of lights.
Make a sprite for the glow, and then add it on top of areas of illumination as a separate sprite.
In reference to the comment Dúthomhas left, make use of a shader or texture.
Manually draw the lighting on static parts of your map, but I imagine that would become quite tedious.

These are only a few rough ideas I just came up with, and if you want more you could have a look at how other 2D games handled their lighting.
Overall, there are multiple ways to solve this kind of problem. If you need more information on Godot's 2D Lighting, I recommend having a look at the official documentation for 2D Lighting.
